# How to chain useQuery hooks using react-apollo-hooks

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, react-hooks

I would like to execute 2 queries with hooks where the second query uses information retrieved in the first one. For example:

```
const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(GET_DOGS);
const result2 = useQuery(GET_BREEDS, { variables: { dogId: data[0].id } });
```

Right now I do it using some state and setting the `skip` parameter on the second hook, however I figure there must be some easier solution which I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 10):

Hooks cannot be conditional, so you can't utilize an `if` statement or an early return like we would do with a `Query` component. For better or for worse, using the `skip` parameter *is* the simplest solution:

```js
const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(GET_DOGS);
const result2 = useQuery(GET_BREEDS, {
  skip: !data,
  variables: { dogId: data && data.dogs[0].id },
});
```

Incidentally, it's not all that different than how you would probably handle it if it were 2017 and we were still using [HOCs and recompose](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/recompose).

Comment: Exactly, that's why i indeed didn't include the conditional case. Something's telling me that the plain old `fetch` was nicer to play with? Do you know of a way to use graphql queries similar to `fetch` when using react-apollo?

Comment: I'm trying to follow your example. In my code, I get the error `Cannot read property dogs of undefined`. It seems like that data gets evaluated anyway before the query is skipped. How do you get around that? Does this actually work?

Comment: @7ball `data` will be initially undefined, so your code should reflect that. I've updated the answer so it's clearer.